# key bindings for nested gnu screens

Tags: gnu-screen

I would like to make a keybinding that works in a nested gnu screen session. For example; in an NON-nested session, I use `bindkey "^[[1;5D" focus left` to focus on the left window. What would be the command to do this for a nested screen session?
In other words; how can I make a keybinding that has the effect: `^A a: focus left`?

Thanks!